# Consider sequences of length 9 consisting of digits: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6. How many among them have both digits 3 before digit 4?

Tags: combinatorics

okay so i understood how to calculate the total number of numbers that can be formed from these digits. But i am not sure about the second part. Can anyone help me with this???c

Answer (score 2):

If you consider only the digits $3,3,4$, there are $3$ different ways in which they can be arranged, and in $1$ of them the $4$ is last. Each case allows for the same number of arrangements of the remaining digits. Thus $\frac13$ of the arrangements without this constraint satisfy this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Although Joriki's argument is most probably the most elegant way to solve this problem, you can also find the number of appropriate sequences in a constructive way.

Consider sequences of length $9$ of the form

$$x\;3\;y\;3\;z\;4\;w$$

where $x,y,z,w$ stands for the number of digits chosen from $1,1,2,2,5,6$ (without replacement) present at the given positions.

Then you have $x,y,z,w \geq 0$ and $x+y+z+w=6$

There are $\binom{6+3}{3}$ ways to choose numbers $x,y,z,w$ of digits for the indicated positions.

For each of these ways you have $\frac{6!}{2!\cdot 2!}$ permutations of the digits $1,1,2,2,5,6$.

Hence, you get

$$\binom{9}{3}\cdot \frac{6!}{2!\cdot 2!}$$

This is in compliance with Joriki's approach since

$$\binom{9}{3}\cdot \frac{6!}{2!\cdot 2!} = \frac 13 \cdot \frac{9!}{2!\cdot 2! \cdot 2!}$$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to trancelocation's construction, start with the sequence $334$ and then "grow" it to a sequence of length $9$ by sequentially "wedging" in the numbers $1_1$, $1_2$, $2_1$, $2_2$, $5$, and $6$, which can be done in $4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9$ ways, and finally divide by $2\cdot2$ to account for the orderings of $1_1,1_2$ and $2_1,2_2$. The answer is thus

$$5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9=15{,}120$$

which agrees with trancelocation's answer.